# Fpdf make filname time

Tags: php, variables, time, fpdf

Working with fpdf, having the problem that I want the filename to be the time now in hours, minutes, and seconds.

```
$timezone = "Europe/Oslo";
 date_default_timezone_set($timezone);
 $format="%H%M%S";
$strf=strftime($format);
```

Having the problem how to put the variable with the .pdf. Because this way didn't work:

```
$pdf->Output('$strf.pdf', 'D');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Variables must be wrapped in double quotes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing), or else PHP will output them literally (`$strf.pdf` rather than `123456.pdf`).

`$pdf->Output("$strf.pdf", 'D');` or `$pdf->Output($strf . '.pdf', 'D');`

I personally prefer the second, since I think it is easier to read and comprehend.  I only use variables in double-quoted strings when it is a very long string with multiple variables and concatenating strings and variables can get messy.

Comment: Please accept it if it helped, so others know.  Glad I could help.